# Difficulty settings carryover to game scenes via playerprefs

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting

Thx to some excellent suggstions, I have Difficulty buttons changing spawn rate for my game. However, the changes aren't translating to subsequent scenes. Can anyone spot the issue with my Playerprefs settings?

Difficulty buttons script

private Button button;

```
public RandomSpawn randomSpawn;

public int difficulty;


void Start()
{
    button = GetComponent<Button>(); 
    randomSpawn = GameObject.Find("Random Spawn").GetComponent<RandomSpawn>();
    button.onClick.AddListener(delegate{randomSpawn.UpdateSpawnRate(difficulty);});
}

void SetDifficulty()
{
    Debug.Log(gameObject.name + "was clicked");
}

 void Update()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player Difficulty", difficulty);
}
```

}

Spawn script

```
public GameObject prefab1, prefab2, prefab3, prefab4;

public float maxSpawnRate = 2f;

private float nextSpawn = 0f;

private int whatToSpawn;

private float spawnRate = 2f;

public static int difficulty = 0;

private void Start()
{
    difficulty = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player Difficulty");
}

void Update()
{
    
    if (Time.time > nextSpawn) { //if time has come
        whatToSpawn = Random.Range(1, 6); // define random value between 1 and 4 (5 is exclusive)
        Debug.Log(whatToSpawn); //display its value in console
   
   
        switch (whatToSpawn) {
            case 1:
                Instantiate(prefab1, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                break;
            case 2:
                Instantiate(prefab2, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                break;
            case 3:
                Instantiate(prefab3, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                break;
            case 4:
                Instantiate(prefab4, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                break;
       
        }
 
        nextSpawn = Time.time + spawnRate;
    }
}

public void UpdateSpawnRate(int difficulty)
{
    spawnRate = maxSpawnRate / difficulty;
}
```

}

SetDifficulty is not showing up as an option for the Inspector's OnClick  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7aMo.png)

Comment: Callbacks added on runtime will never appear in the Inspector for `onClick`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is using the `SetInt` in the `Update()` method as you have several objects using the `RandomSpawn` script. It will keep overwriting this value with the difficulty of each object.

```
private Button button;

public int difficulty;


void Start()
{
    button = GetComponent<Button>();

    // can also add the onclick to your button here
    button.onClick.AddListener(delegate{SetDifficulty();});
}

// make this your buttons onClick in the hierarchy
public void SetDifficulty()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player Difficulty", difficulty);
    Debug.Log(gameObject.name + "was clicked");
}
}
```

Is the SetDifficulty the onClick of the buttons? If so, you do not need the button.onClick.AddListener anymore if you are assigning the onClick in the inspector. I would move the PlayerPrefs.SetInt to wherever the onClick is occurring for your button so you can set the difficulty just in that instance instead of every frame in Update().

I am now editing the spawn script to change the spawnRate based on the difficulty and maxSpawn;

```
public GameObject prefab1, prefab2, prefab3, prefab4;

public float maxSpawnRate = 2f;

private float nextSpawn = 0f;

private int whatToSpawn;

private float spawnRate = 2f;

public static int difficulty = 0;

private void Start()
{
    difficulty = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player Difficulty");
    spawnRate = maxSpawnRate / difficulty;
}

void Update()
{
    
    if (Time.time > nextSpawn) { //if time has come
        whatToSpawn = Random.Range(1, 6); // define random value between 1 and 4 (5 is exclusive)
        Debug.Log(whatToSpawn); //display its value in console
   
   
        switch (whatToSpawn) {
            case 1:
                Instantiate(prefab1, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                break;
            case 2:
                Instantiate(prefab2, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                break;
            case 3:
                Instantiate(prefab3, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                break;
            case 4:
                Instantiate(prefab4, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                break;
       
        }
 
        nextSpawn = Time.time + spawnRate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for the rapid response. I removed the button.onclick line and pasted in the above mods but still no transfer of settings to subsequent scenes. I noticed that changing maxspawnrate in the box generated by randomspawn in the Inspector of subsequent scenes also has no impact on the spawner. Seems like we're oh so close, but something is still off.  Debug log is clean, but oddly doesn't show anything for "was clicked"--before it would acknowledge when Easy etc clicked

Comment: @xaltx Did you post the entire script of both? I am noticing in the Spawner script that there is no code that influences the spawnRate anymore. I updated the code so it should work.

Comment: appears to be working now!!! adjustments to maxspawn in Inspector helped. Doing a more thorough level by level check now--will report back when done.

Comment: @xaltx Glad to hear! Hope it all works now.

Comment: Confirmed everything working! @TEEBQNE Thx so much for your kindness, time & patience.

Comment: Happy to hear and anytime!

Comment: hi there. on the final hurdle before completing my first game solo as a total noob. I'm having issues with my score preservation scripts not communicating properly with my replay level script (which reduces score to 0). No matter what changes I make, either replay resets to 0 but score is not preserved or score is preserved but replay won't reset to 0. -if you have time for any guidance, pls check out this post--many thx in advance: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67067412/unity-reset-score-to-0-on-replay

Comment: @xaltx Sure I can check it out